# How can I install a SSH daemon in msysgit

Tags: msysgit, sshd

How can I install an SSH daemon in my msysgit environment so that I can use a SSH client to access msysgit? The reason behind this is that I don't like the default command window that is used by msysgit. Instead, I'd like to access it via Putty. Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, belongs on super user

Answer (score 1):

You can get it working in cygwin but you have to change the paths for cygwin ssh which doesn't look at .bash_profile like you'd expect.

https://superuser.com/questions/325639/make-msysgit-work-with-cygwin-ssh